# How do I get the specific position of a value within an array, rather than the value

Tags: c++, arrays

The question itself is pretty simple.

Here's my code:

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int const SIZE = 5;



int main(){

    string flav[SIZE] = {"Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"};
    int cnt[SIZE];
    int total=0;
    int max=0;

    for(int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please Input the number of jars sold for "<<flav[i]<<"."<<endl;
        cin>>cnt[i];
        total = cnt[i] + total;
    }

    cout << "The total amount of Salsa sold was "<<total<<" units."<<endl;

    for(int i = 1; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(cnt[i] > max)
            max = cnt.at[i];
    }

    cout <<"The highest selling flavor was "<< flav[max]<<endl;




}`
```

I want to assign max to the position of the highest value within the array, NOT the value itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

edit:  Cool.  New problem.  Ugh.
[image]

Comment: instead of searching forwards, you could start at the end and go backwards thus stopping the search the first time you encounter the value

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int maxvalue = cnt[0];
int maxidx = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (cnt[i] > maxvalue)
    {
        maxvalue = cnt[i];
        maxidx = i;
    }
}
```

**Update**: As for your other error, `cnt` is not a `class` or `struct`, and it does not have an `at[]` member. It is just a plain ordinary array, so you need to replace `cnt.at[i]` with `cnt[i]`.

You are also missing required braces around the `if` statement inside of the loop, so you are always setting `iMaxIdx = i` unconditionally on every loop interation:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    if(cnt[i] > max) // <-- no braces
        max = cnt.at[i]; // <-- only executed on higher values
        iMaxIdx = i; // <-- always executed unconditionally
}
```

As such, `iMaxIdx` will *always* be `SIZE-1` when the loop exits.  You need to add braces so that `iMaxIdx` is updated only on the iterations where a higher value is found, as shown in my example above:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    if(cnt[i] > max)
    { // <-- add this
        max = cnt[i]; // <-- not cnt.at[i]
        iMaxIdx = i;  // <-- only executed on higher values
    } // <-- add this
}
```

Comment: max contains index and you use it in the comparison with out indexing in the cnt first

Comment: The for loop is setting the value for maxidx to whatever position it's checking.  How do I stop this?

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin: that is what you asked for: "I want to assign max to the position of the highest value within the array". That is what the loop is doing. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `int iMaxIdx;` and when ever you update `max` update `iMaxIdx` too

```
    for(int i = 1; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(cnt[i] > max){
            max = cnt.at[i];
            iMaxIdx = i;
        }
    }
    // now use iMaxIdx as it contains the index
```

Comment: I dont understand what that is.  How does declaring a random integer help me find the index position?

Comment: It is not random. You are looping through the array, saving the *index* of the highest value found in the array.

Comment: The print command is still returning 'Zesty'

I cant figure out why.   If iMaxIdx contains a value of 3, wouldn't it return hot?

Answer (score 0):

you use a for loop to acess each element of the array, qhen you find the element you want. the For iterator value will be the position

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxid=0;
for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    if(cnt[i] > max)
        {
            max = cnt[i];
            maxid=i;
        }
}

cout <<"The highest selling flavor was "<< flav[maxid]<<endl;
```

Edited the last section. This is what you want I believe?

Comment: This still returns whatever value the last spot checked was rather than the highest spot.

at least thats what i think is going on.

everyone's answer is returning zesty when the program receives input of 100, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0.   If the last one was the highest, Zesty would be right.   :/